# Ember Bootstrap disabled text input box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, ember.js, input

I'm having some trouble making a bootstrap text input field disabled after putting handlebars around the input. Is there a way to do this or should I be taking a different approach. I eventually want to be able to click an EDIT button and be able to edit/save these fields.

Works:

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" value="Jim" disabled>
```

Doesn't work:

```
{{input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" value=this.name disabled}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a value to the property, when using the ember syntax. This works fine:

```
{{input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" value=this.name disabled=true}}
```

Here's an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sadoqenaji/1/edit